# RichFaces 4.3.4 : <rich:dataScroller> pages facet not working to show footer mesage under datatable

Tags: richfaces

In RichFaces 4.3.4, pages facet was not working to show total No. of pages and current page.
Please some one provide me the sample code how to show the footer message.

Ex : 1(current page) to 10(rows in one page) of 53(Total No.of rows in dataTable).

```
<rich:dataScroller for="table" pageIndexVar="pageIndex" pagesVar="pages" fastControls="hide" stepControls="hide" bypassUpdates="true" renderIfSinglePage="true"> 
    <f:facet name="pages"> 
    <h:outputText value="#{pageIndex} / #{pages}" /> </f:facet> 
    <f:facet name="first"><h:outputText value="Prev"/> </f:facet> 
    <f:facet name="last"><h:outputText value="Next"/> </f:facet>
</rich:dataScroller>
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried, then we can tell you why it isn't working.

Comment: I tried by using below code.It shows the pagination as expected,but not showing the note mentioned in "pages" facet.<rich:dataScroller for="table" pageIndexVar="pageIndex" pagesVar="pages" fastControls="hide" stepControls="hide" bypassUpdates="true" renderIfSinglePage="true"  >
            <f:facet name="pages">
                <h:outputText value="#{pageIndex} / #{pages}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="first"><h:outputText value="Prev"/>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="last"><h:outputText value="Next"/>
            </f:facet> </rich:dataScroller>

Comment: Could you edit your question and put the code in there? It's hard to read it like this. Also what note are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

`pagesVar` and `pageIndexVar` are not valid attributes in RichFaces 4. Use this instead:

```
<rich:dataScroller id="scroller" page="#{bean.currentPage}" …>
    <f:facet name="pages">
        #{bean.currentPage} / #{rich:findComponent('scroller').pageCount}
    </f:facet>
</rich:dataScroller>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.but pages facet is not working seems it got removed in Richfaces 4.3.4.I tried to keep sample text in pages,that is also not showing.

Comment: You might have started with that. Yes, unfortunately the facet is not supported in 4.x until RichFaces 4.5.